# Parametrise distribution of vectors with non-negative dot product with known vector under some contraints

Tags: statistics, vectors, 3d

I'm looking for a general way to parametrise the distribution of of vectors that have a non-negative dot-product with a known vector. I believe this is a more general version of the question asked in [all vectors making $ \text{negative dot product} $ with the vector $(1,1,1)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939229/all-vectors-making-textnegative-dot-product-with-the-vector-1-1-1).

The motivation of the problem is to parametrise the distribution of vectors that point away from the origin of a 3-D (Cartesian) space at a location $\vec{r}$. This is required to find which possible vectors point away from the centre of the volume to provide gradient constraints to a Gaussian Process.

If I understand the related question correctly, my first step should be to find the plane that is normal to $\vec{r}$ (which I remember being taught how to do once upon a time, but have since forgotten - I'm sure I can figure it out again, but pointers would be helpful). However, once I have identified that plane, I am struggling to understand how I determine the distribution of vectors that meet my needs. Ideally I would like to sample from the distribution of x, y and z components for these vectors. I can place some constraints on the range of projections in the direction of $\vec{r}$ to limit the length of these vectors.

Any help would be appreciated, and I will happily try to clarify anything that is unclear!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to `parameterize` the distribution of vectors you seek? 'Finding' the distribution is a bit imprecise. Technically, you have already found your distribution as soon as you have defined it, which you did

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant! Apologies, I'm an astronomer, so may make some mistakes with the terminology. I'll update the question, thanks!

Comment: No worries, I am not attacking your question, just clarifying :)

Comment: If $\vec{r}=(r_x,r_y,r_z)$ then I suspect the plane you are looking for is $r_x x+ r_y y+ r_zz =0$ and the vectors $(x,y,z)$ which make a non-negative dot product with $\vec{r}$ are those where $r_x x+ r_y y+ r_zz \ge 0$.  Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: @Henry like I said, it's been a very long time since I've had to do anything like this, but that seems to ring some bells. Then I want to find a simple parametrisation for the distributions of $\left(x, y, z\right)$ that fulfil that inequality for a given $\vec{r}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

$$\vec{v}(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) = \alpha \vec{e}_r + \beta \vec{e}_b + \gamma \vec{e}_c$$

Where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are real numbers, and $\vec{e}_r, \vec{e}_b, \vec{e}_c$ are 3 [orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality) vectors. So $\vec{e}_r$ points in the same direction as your $\vec{r}$, ant the other two vectors are orthogonal to it. Additional constraint that you require is $\alpha \geq 0$, whereas the other two numbers can be arbitrary.

The only remaining thing to do is to find the vectors $\vec{e}_b, \vec{e}_c$. The procedure to do this is called [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Comment: So if I understand this right, once I have defined $\vec{e}_{r}, \vec{e}_b, \vec{e}_c$, I can allow $\beta$ and $\gamma$ to be arbitrary real numbers and then place any constraints I need on $\alpha$ (ideally, I would force this to conform to a particular distribution, but just forcing non-negativity would be a good start) and then parametrise or sample from the distributions of $v_x, v_y, v_z$ (where those are the components of $\vec{v}$)?

Comment: @peter If I understood your question correctly, then yes, that is what you would do. You can enforce some distributions on $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ (e.g. exponential on $\alpha$ and gaussian on $\beta$ and $\gamma$) and then sample from the distribution. You could even convert your 3 vectors to cylindrical or spherical coordinates if your probability distribution follows that kind of symmetry.